# 2002 VW Passat headlight warning beeper only works after closing door once

Tags: electrical, vw, door

I have a 2002 VS Passat GLS Wagon that I've had for the last few years.

I have a problem where I leave the headlights on far too often. I know I should learn to not leave them on but 3 dead batteries later, I have not been able to learn the lesson.

Looking into the issue, the car does have a "you left your headlights on" warning. It's the same warning as "you left your keys in the ignition". It works, too. But *only* after opening and closing the door once.

So, if I drive somewhere, leave my lights on when I arrive, and then get out normally, the beeps don't happen. But if I go back into my car, because let's say I forgot my sweatshirt, as soon as I open the door, I hear the alert chime and am reminded to turn off the lights.

This feels like unintentional behavior. I should get notified as soon as I open the door the **first** time.

The door sensors all seem to work as expected otherwise. Dome lights turn on whenever the door is opened.

I'm not sure where to look. I've been scouring Google for this issue for a while and never found someone with a similar problem. But maybe I'm not looking in the right places.

Comment: It's just a guess, but if the door switch is working properly, then it may be the headlight switch. Or possibly the body control module.

Comment: The headlights work as expected. What are you suggesting could be wrong with the headlight switch? I feel like this has to be a failed switch but some other switch is basically being a backup with the computer. I'd be surprised if the computer had this internal software/firmware failure, but I guess it's possible.

Comment: The body control modules typically fail less often then other things and are usually toward the last end of diagnosing. My train of thought is the BCM is not getting the signal to turn on the chime at the proper time. The components that would probably contribute to that signal would be the door switch and the headlight switch or the BCM misinterpretting a signal. Or maybe even more likely not receiving the right signal because of a damaged wire or connector.